# eslint: no-plusplus set to 0 but still work

Tags: eslint

In my project, I came across a confusing point about eslint.

currently, the eslint check report many `no-plusplus` error for the operation of `++` or `--`.

And in my project, most of such operations are in the for loop. So I check the eslint document, and want to disable the checking by following settings:

`'no-plusplus': ['error', { "allowForLoopAfterthoughts": true }]`

but the errors are still reported.

Then I tried `'no-plusplus': 0`

But the errors are still there.

My eslint version is 3.x.

so what's wrong with my setting?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? The setting looks fine. So, I wonder what caused this.

Comment: I resolved it with "no-plusplus" :  [ 0 ]  ESLint told me the answer "Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error"